# Send PIL image to front without saving it

Tags: flask, python-imaging-library

I'm learning flask and i got stuck in this part.

I want to send a image to a img HTML tag without saving it...

here is where i got so far

PYTHON

```
def serve_pil_image(pil_img):
    img_io = BytesIO()
    pil_img.save(img_io, 'JPEG', quality=70)
    img_io.seek(0)
    return send_file(img_io, mimetype='image/jpeg')

@app.route('/upload', methods=["POST"])
def upload():
    target = os.path.join(APP_ROOT, 'static/images')

    # create image directory if not found
    if not os.path.isdir(target):
        os.mkdir(target)

    # retrieve file from HTML -- NO SAVING
    for upload in request.files.getlist("file"):
        print('Getting ', upload)
        img = Image.open(upload)
    return render_template('processing.html')

@app.route('/static/images')
def serve_img():
    img = poster
    return serve_pil_image(img)
```

HTML

```
<img src="{{ url_for('serve_img', filename=img) }}" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know a little JavaScript you could create a url within the window using `createObjectURL`. Store the blob content that got sent by `Flask.send_file` in the created object. Get a reference to the image tag, and make it point to the in memory url.